# Is it safe to store bitcoins on p2sh (no multisig)?

Tags: script, bitcoin-core-development, input-script

I've just generated p2sh btc address and look in the output script:

```
HASH160 PUSHDATA(20)[e5c32bdc7f7fb1e6ae7aa1baf42a429803054d2c] EQUALVERIFY
```

while normal (legacy btc address) transaction has signature check

```
DUP HASH160 PUSHDATA(20)[e5c32bdc7f7fb1e6ae7aa1baf42a429803054d2c]
EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG
```

Is it safe to store bitcoins in this address with this scriptsig ?

Or it use a same key for the signature check? 
If yes, what a reason to check the signature ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to store bitcoins in this address with this scriptsig ?

That is actually the `scriptPubkey`, and it is only safe if you use a safe `redeemScript`.

A P2SH script is a [Pay-to-Script-Hash](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-Script-Hash) script, meaning when you spend the coins, you must provide the script (and the hash must match), but this script you provide, called the `redeemScript` must also succeed when it is executed, and can be any valid script.

Typically this is a script similar (if not exactly the same) as the one you provided, which is a P2PKH or [Pay-to-Public-Key-Hash](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-PubkeyHash). Thus, it also requires a signature, so if you use a P2SH(P2PKH) it is still just as secure as using a `P2PKH` because of the signature requirement in the P2PKH, you just have to also provide the `redeemScript`.